# browser version detection from server side with java

Tags: java, jsp, browser, version

I saw many posts related to the browser detection, User agent detection etc...I want to detect the version from server side and send appropriate data based on that.

I know browsers can mimic version with tools, but that doesn't matter for me.

I need the java solution for the exact version detection.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to detect browser version is by inspecting the "headers". Logically it makes sense also, as the server can not go to each "client" and find out information about it - it has to rely on the information provided by the client when the client comes to browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [`user-agent-utils`](https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils).

Comment: User agent Utils are really useful. It returns the exact version with two lines of coding.

Comment: @coder247 - can you share the code snippet... I googled it but still was not able to find it

Answer (score 22):

Here is the code explaining how to do it using **user-agent-utils**:

```
String userAgent = req.getHeader("user-agent");
UserAgent ua = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgent);
Version browserVersion = ua.getBrowserVersion();
String browserName = ua.getBrowser().toString();
int majVersion = Integer.parseInt(browserVersion.getMajorVersion());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the headers in the HTTP servlet request - they'll tell you.  Check the "User-Agent" header.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spring Mobile Device Module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/device.html)?

This can use either the [LiteDeviceResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/mobile/device/LiteDeviceResolver.html) or the [WurflDeviceResolver](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend UA Detector at [uadetector.sourceforge.net](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net)