# Show error page in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC. I'm trying to write a controller that handles a particular route. This controller renders a View jsp and returns it.

I now want to add an error page in some particular cases (e.g., browser not supported)

How do I do that in spring?

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but here is what I've found so far: [preHandle Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-)

I can add some sort of interceptor before the controller and check if the error condition is met. Based on that I can show an error page or continue with regular flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest two possibilities.

**1. Use handler interceptor.** You are right. I believe this is the best option. Detect the browser type before controller and then use the browser information to show the right page.

Look at this example **pseudo code**, you will need the library [user-agent-utils](https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils):

```
public class BrowserInfo {

    private String name;
    private int version;

    public BrowserInfo(String name, int version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    // getter, setter...
}

/**
* Detect browser type and make it available in your controller
*/
public class BrowserResolverHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        //
        // FROM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13229552/1614378
        //
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
        UserAgent ua     = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgent);

        Version browserVersion  = ua.getBrowserVersion();
        String browserName      = ua.getBrowser().toString();
        int majVersion          = Integer.parseInt(browserVersion.getMajorVersion());

        BrowserInfo browser = new BrowserInfo(browserName, majVersion);
        request.setAttribute("browserInfo", browser);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
* HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. so you can use BrowserInfo as argument in you controller methods.
*/
public class BrowserInfoResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(BrowserInfo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        return (BrowserInfo) webRequest.getAttribute("browserInfo", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class RootController extends AbstractWebController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(BrowserInfo browser, Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if("ie".equals(browser.getName()) && browser.getVersion() < 7){
            return "redirect:error"; // error.jsp or browser_not_supported.jsp...
        }

        return "home"; // home.jsp
    }
}
```

**2. Detect the (IE) browser version in your jsp:** [About conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx)

Example:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <style>
        [styles for IE 8]
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <style>
        [styles for IE 7: hide all elements, show message label etc...]
    </style>
    <script>
         alert("Pls update your browser. now!");
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

**EDIT:** 
(3.) you can also send redirect inside interceptor. But I *personally* do not like that. Because you will split your "page logic" between `Interceptor` and `Controller`. Anyway i believe redirect by interceptor  would be faster than redirect by controller.

Comment: examples that I found online, were adding a redirect in the interceptor ( redirect to /error and then some other controller handles it) instead of passing a flag  and handling it in main controller. what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @sublime i updated my answer. but it is just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Check it in a filter or a beforeInterceptor to throw an exception.

make a custom error code for your exception.

e.g Browser not supported to be - 450 and map them through web.xml like below

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>450</error-code>
 <location>/450</location>
</error-page>
```

now make a controller that handles this error.

[take a look at this example for reference](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/custom-error-404-error-page-in-spring-mvc.html)