# Is there a way to find the browser and OS in which my Japplet is running?

Tags: java

I'm interested if there is a way to find out from java applet the OS and the browser in which my java applet is running on client side?

Comment: Did you try: `String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [browser version detection from server side with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469159/browser-version-detection-from-server-side-with-java)

Comment: Not a duplicate of "detect from server side". This one is about applets (client side).

Comment: @Thilo yes, thank you! And I would like to also find the OS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect OS using:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name"); 
String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
```

For detecting browser you can check this [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-browser-type-from-an-applet.html).